# Chmod and -r +r

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I have tried calling the command chmod in the wrong order. `chmod file.txt -r` This worked for some reason. `chmod file.txt +r` On the other hand refused to work. Why is this? For what reason does one command work, and the other not?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a quirk of how GNU chmod handles input, and is not portable to all POSIX-compatible chmod implementations.

Note that the [POSIX `chmod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html) coomand-line syntax *requires* mode to come first, as does [GNU `chmod`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chmod-invocation.html#chmod-invocation) (options should come before mode, too). Anything else is an undocumented implementation quirk.

---

Now, onto why it happens in this particular implementation:

It's hinted at in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chmod-invocation.html#chmod-invocation):

> Typically, though, ‘`chmod a-w file`’ is preferable, and `chmod -w file` (without the `--`) complains if it behaves differently from what ‘`chmod a-w file`’ would do.

Briefly, options parsed by `getopt` are prefixed with a `-`. Like in `ls -a`, `a` is an option. The long form `ls --all` has `all` as an option. `rm -rf` (equivalent to `rm -r -f`) has both `r` and `f` options.

Everything else is a non-option argument, technically called *operands*. I like to call these *positional* arguments, as their meaning is determined by their relative position. In `chmod`, the first positional argument is the mode and the second positional argument is the file name.

Optimally, mode should not lead with a `-`. If it does, you should use `--` to force parsing as an operand instead of an option (i.e. use `chmod a-w file` or `chmod -- -w file` instead of `chmod -w file`. This is also [suggested](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html#tag_20_17_16) by POSIX.

---

If you look at [the source code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/chmod.c?h=v8.30#n435), you'll notice it uses [getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) to parse command-line options. Here, there's special handling for 'incorrect' modes like `-w`:

```
    case 'r':
    case 'w':
    case 'x':
    case 'X':
    case 's':
    case 't':
    case 'u':
    case 'g':
    case 'o':
    case 'a':
    case ',':
    case '+':
    case '=':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3':
    case '4': case '5': case '6': case '7':
      /* Support nonportable uses like "chmod -w", but diagnose
         surprises due to umask confusion.  Even though "--", "--r",
         etc., are valid modes, there is no "case '-'" here since
         getopt_long reserves leading "--" for long options.  */
```

Taking your example:

- `chmod a-r file.txt` would be the *most robust* invocation.
- `chmod +r file.txt` works because the first argument is positionally interpreted as the mode.
- `chmod -r file.txt` still works because the `-r` is interpreted as a short `r` option and special-cased.
- `chmod -- -r file.txt` is correct and works because the `-r` is positionally interpreted as the mode. This differs from the case without `--` because with `--` the `-r` is not interpreted as an *option*.
- `chmod file.txt -r` still works because the `-r` is interpreted as a short `r` option and special-cased. Options are not position-dependent. This technically abuses an undocumented quirk.
- `chmod file.txt +r` does not work because the `+r` is a operand, not an option. The first operand (`file.txt`) is interpreted as a mode ... and fails to parse.

Comment: This can have interesting consequences if you have a file named, for example, `a+rwx` and do something like `chmod * +r`, and the `a+rwx` file happens to come first in the glob expansion.

Comment: Or a file named "-rf" in case of "rm *".

Comment: @Edheldil Yep you are right. This seems like something that should be addressed (and a bug, just like if input wasn't sanitized properly.

Comment: Note that OP syntax is not POSIX http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html#SCANNING_MODES

Comment: @StevenPenny That's irrelevant. Firstly, the linked manpage is section 1, i.e. the `getopt` *command*, not the *library routine* in [section 3](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html). Secondly, that's referring to the `optstring`, i.e. the list of accepted options (in `chmod` source `optstring` is set to `"Rcfvr::w::x::X::s::t::u::g::o::a::,::+::=::"`). The linked "SCANNING MODES" section has nothing to do with the *argument array* `argv` that contains the args passed into the program.

Comment: @StevenPenny That said, I've updated the answer to make the exact mechanism of POSIX-incompatibility clearer.